# Do we call this a flow? and why so.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, derivatives, gradient-flows

Let $\Phi:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable.

Suppose we have a curve $\gamma_t$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$, i.e $\gamma : [0,T]\to \mathbb{R}^d$, which evolves according to

\begin{equation}
    \partial_t \gamma_t = -\nabla \Phi(\gamma_t).
\end{equation}

Do we call $\gamma_t$ the flow of $\Phi$? If so why?

Comment: What is your definition of a flow?

Answer (score 1):

This type of problem, when we have a "potential" function $\Phi : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$, is sometimes called the gradient flow problem. This is because the solution $\gamma$ to the problem flows along the gradient of the potential. It is in contrast to the Newtonian problem when the second derivative is equated to the gradient, i.e. $\partial_t^2 \gamma_t = \pm \nabla \Phi(\gamma_t)$.